# Filtering results of Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm chaining a series of Promises to operate with a database. From a first Promise, I retrieve an array of objects. In the second Promise, I generate a Promise for each object. Then, I filter the results. Here is a code example:

```
db.getUser(user)
  .then(user=> Promise.all(
    user.shirts.map(userShirt => db.getShirt(shirt.id))
  ) as Promise<IShirt[]>)
  .then(shirts => {
    shirts = shirts.filter(shirt => shirt.color === 'blue');
    console.log(shirts);
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

This is a simplified example of what my code does. The problem is in the filter operation where I retrive a 0 lenght array. Any idea?

Comment: Whats the output if you run console.log(shirts) right before the filter?

Comment: The concept of a database is doing filtering. Why don't you query just what you need?

Comment: That's just means you don't have a blue shirt.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the promises produced by the calls to `getShirt`, then run them together. Promise all will produce an array of the resolutions of those promises.

**EDIT** I see that you do have a Promise.all in the OP.  The simple solution is to fix the undefined temp variable name:

```
user.shirts.map(userShirt => db.getShirt(shirt.id)) // shirt is undefined
user.shirts.map(userShirt => db.getShirt(userShirt.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you fix the `filter` operation when you retrieve a 0 length array.

One of your variable names is off:

```js
db.getUser(user)
  .then(user=> Promise.all(
    user.shirts.map(userShirt => db.getShirt(shirt.id)) // <- perhaps you meant `userShirt.id` here?
  ))
  .then(shirts => {
    shirts = shirts.filter(shirt => shirt.color === 'blue')
    console.log('shirts')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err),
  })
```

You could be fine with that, though the bigger issue here is having to worry about `Promise.all` in the first place. I wrote a [library](https://github.com/richytong/rubico) so you wouldn't have to worry about boilerplate Promise code.

Below is code equivalent to your example written with functions `pipe`, `map`, `filter`, `get`, and `eq` from my library:

```js
const db = {} // your db instance here

const getBlueShirts = pipe([
  db.getUser,
  get('shirts'),
  map(pipe([get('id'), db.getShirt])),
  filter(eq('blue', get('color'))),
])

tryCatch(getBlueShirts, console.error)(user)
```

further, you could `map` and `filter` in one fell swoop by using `transform`. When you use `transform`, `map(...)` and `filter(...)` become transducers composed with `pipe`.

```js
const getBlueShirts = pipe([
  db.getUser,
  get('shirts'),
  transform(pipe([ // pipe([map(...), filter(...)]) is a transducer
    map(pipe([get('id'), db.getShirt])),
    filter(eq('blue', get('color'))),
  ]), [])
])
```

I write more about transducers [here](https://github.com/richytong/rubico#transducers)